# How can i find the number of disk accesses needed for a relational algebra query?

Tags: sql, relational-database, rel

Hello are any of you very nice people able to explain the concept of query optimization to me in regards to relational algebra?

my preferred method of constructing relational algebra queries is by using temporary values step by step, but the only resources i can find for explaining how query optimization works to find the amount of disk access needed uses different notation for relational algebra queries, which confuses me.

so if i am given the following relations:

department(**deptNo**, deptName, location)

Employee(**empNo**, empName, empAddress, jobDesc, deptNo*)

and have produced the following relational algebra query to find all the programmers who work in a Manchester department as so:

temp1 = department JOIN employee

temp 2 = SELECT(jobdesc = 'programmer') (temp1)

result = SELECT(location = 'Manchester)(temp 2)

And i can assume that there are 10,00 tuples in the employee relation, 50 tuples in the department relation, 100 programmers (2 in each department) and one department located in Manchester, how would i work out how many disk accesses are needed?

Thankyou in advance!

Comment: I think you should choose a database (something like Postgres, MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, or something similar).  Learn SQL.  Learn how the database does optimization.  The amount of disk access depends on many factors, such as the query, the software, the hardware, the version of the software, configuration parameters, and the nature of the data.  And, I've no doubt left more stuff out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup - Gordon's right.  However, this is an academic exercise: you're building sets of data - assume each element/tuple returned by a sub-query is one disk access.  General rule of thumb - limit the most amount of data as early as possible.  Lets assume you do the JOIN first (10000 employees + 50 departments = 10050 disk entries {even thought he number of rows returned is 10000!}), then you do the SELECT (assuming that the sub-query is perfectly indexed) = (100 programmers + 1 department in Manchester) thus the total number of "accesses" = 10050+101 = 10151.

If you do the SELECTS first, the whole exercise changes dramatically:  (temp 1=get programmers = 100 rows/disk accesses), (temp 2=get departments = 1 row/disk access), JOIN (again, assuming perfect indexing on temporary views/queries, etc, etc) = 50 rows: therefore total number of "accesses" = 100+1+50 = 151.

Same results, but the way it is interpreted and executed can influence the amount of work the database engine has to perform.

It's been many years, every possibility that I might have got this wrong - I don't mind being corrected.